# How would i start a process in ruby and monitor it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to start a process, capture output give it input and monitor this process. Right now I am using fork and capturing the pid to check that it is running and kill it if needed. I am looking at converting this to sidekiq but im not sure this is the best for this.

Input is appreciated.

Ruby on rails
- start process
- capture process IO and write to database
- ensure process is running
- end process

Comment: Ive been looking at God http://godrb.com/ Monit http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples and sidekiq. Not sure what would fit best.

Answer (score 0):

See also `Delayed_Job`. And a module written by someone else is infinitely preferable to rolling your own with `fork`, because a Rails app running on a real web server must expect to frequently shut down and restart, and `fork` won't be aware of this.